# Late night transportation in Leipzig

Tags: public-transport, germany, airport-transfer, leipzig, lej

I'll arrive in Leipzig/Halle Airport (LEJ) at 22:45 around the midnight, I want to move from the airport to the central station (specifically A&O hostel).

Is there any public transportation available at midnight?
I've heared of the Nightliner buses. Do they pass by the airport? Where should I wait for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The train Halle - Leipzig/Halle Airport - Leipzig](http://www.leipzig-halle-airport.de/media/files/lej/reisende_besucher/anreise_parken/regio_s_13.pdf) should work fine for you. You have a train at 23:38 and another one at 00:43. You can find the train station [here](http://www.leipzig-halle-airport.de/en/index/reisende_besucher/terminalplan/bahnhof.html?newLanguage=en).

Comment: Tickets are bought from the train of the station ?

Comment: Not in the train. There should be ticket machines at the station.